# can i set a placeholder on a page layout fields

Tags: lightning-experience

I am wondering if I can set a place holder in a page layout field for example I added a custom phone field and I am wondering if I can add a place holder say +1(xxx)xxxx-xxxx
tried making a formula field but the results are not satisfacotry.

Comment: Default value and/or field help are your friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, you could pre-populate the field with a default value. However, when saving the record without editing this field, the default value will be saved as well (so its not really a placeholder as it is a 'real' value).

As a best practice, I combine a help-text with validation rules to force the end-user to fill in the correct format.

Also:
Although not beiing officially supported, salesforce classic supports prefilling fields through the URL (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MU7GQAW).